# Error writing to long value to file Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create 9 text files on my Desktop which are named by variable `i` in the `for` loop. Inside each text file I want to write a long value determined by my `bigInt` function. The long value must then be written in the file 1000 times before moving on to the next text file.  But I keep getting the error: `Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString*' to parameter of type 'NSData*'`

My Function:

```
long bigInt(int i){
    long big = 99*(i*99);
    long evenBigger = big*(big*(big*big));
    return evenBigger;

}
```

My main method:

```
long use;
int x = 0;

for (int i = 1; i<10; i++) {

    while (x < 1000) {
        use = bigInt(i);
        //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", use];
        //NSString *content = @"Text to write to file";
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "/Users/ou_snaaksie/Desktop/%i.txt", i];
        //NSData *fileContents = [use dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", use] attributes:nil];
        x++;
    }


}
```

Comment: Signed integer arithemetic is not guaranteed to "wrap around", in fact, overflowing a signed integer type results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: "But I keep getting the error: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString*' to parameter of type 'NSData*'".  Uh, maybe that's because you didn't bother to read the spec for `createFileAtPath`??

Comment: I did, but like I said I am new to objective-c, and did not understand how to add a method to an object. For example: I would've said `dataContents.writeToFile()`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string as contents when it requires NSData. You have to convert the string to NSData. Try this in the body of your while loop:

```
use = bigInt(i);
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", use];
NSData* data_contents = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "/tmp/%i.txt", i];
[data_contents writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
x++;
```

Comment: When I add your block of code to the while loop, it doesn't create my text files

Comment: I think it is because your app isn't allowed to write to the desktop. Change the path to /tmp/%i.txt

Comment: No, I tried a few other paths as well. Can someone please try and successfully run the code? I'm nee to objective-c (coming from Java) and I don't quite understand the NSData

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the way I wrote the file. Try the code above. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass NSData instead of NSString object to `contents` in `createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:` method or you can do something like below:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil];
}

[[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: You have a race condition... there is a chance that a file may be created in between `fileExistsAtPath:` and the subsequent `createFileAtPath:`.